# RSA: why $( e^{-1} ~\text{mod}~ n \cdot \varphi(n)) ~\text{mod}~ \varphi(n) = e^{-1} ~\text{mod}~ \varphi(n)$ holds for a specific setting of RSA

Tags: rsa, number-theory

Let $p,q$ are primes and $n = pq$ as in every RSA setting and now use a random $e$ that holds the following properties

- $gcd(e, \phi(n)) \neq 1$
- $(e^{-1} ~\text{mod} ~\phi(n))^{4}\cdot3 < n$
- $e^{-1} ~\text{mod} ~\phi(n) < \sqrt[3]{n}$ (integer square root), where $\sqrt[3]{n} \in \mathbb{Z}$

where $\phi$ is euler's totient function. This $e$ is used as the public exponent for the public key and $d$ is the private exponent for the private key.

Remember that $\phi(n) | ed - 1$, as $ed = 1 + k \cdot \phi(n)$ holds for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
The question is, why it holds that $$(e^{-1} ~\text{mod}~ n \cdot \phi(n)) ~\text{mod}~ \ \phi(n) = e^{-1} ~\text{mod}~ \phi(n)\text{?}$$
Could someone explain it mathematically or give a proof why that holds?

A related question regarding multiple of $\phi(n)$ is asked in this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6248/recovering-phin-from-a-multiple).
Unfortunately, I don't understand the relation between the multiple of $\phi(n)$, the $gcd$ and why this equation $ed = 1 ~\text{mod}~ k \cdot \phi(n)$ holds $ed = 1 ~\text{mod}~ \phi(n)$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Additionally it would be nice to read a proof for the related question regarding the multiple of $\phi(n)$, if someone knows why that holds.

Comment: $(e^{-1} \bmod \phi(n))^4 \cdot 3 < n$ is certainly not standard with RSA, and I probably yields an RSA public key that is vulnerable to attack.  Are you modelling such a weak RSA key?

Comment: Yes, it should be vulnerable. @poncho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is, why it holds that
> $(e^{−1} \bmod n \cdot \phi(n)) \bmod \phi(n)=e%{−1} \bmod \phi(n)$?

Actually, we have the more general identity $(A \bmod BC) \bmod C \equiv A \bmod C$, for any integers $A, B, C$.  In your specific case, we have $A = e^{-1} \bmod \phi(n)$, $B = n$, and $C = \phi(n)$

This more general identity can be easily be seen from two facts:

$X \bmod Y = X + k \cdot Y$ for some integer $k$ (which may be negative)

$X \bmod Y = Z \bmod Y$ if and only if $X - Z = k'\cdot Y$ for some integer $k'$.

From the first fact, we can see that $A \bmod BC = A + kBC$ (for some integer $k$ - we don't care what that integer is)

From the second fact, we see that $(A + kBC) \bmod C = A \bmod C$ holds if we have $A + kBC - A = k'C$ for some integer $k'$; we can immediately see that this holds for the integer $k' = kB$, hence this is true.

Since the general identity holds in all cases, it also holds in your specific case.

Comment: thank you. I am wondering where the gcd plays a role like it is mentioned in the "correct" answer of the related question on the mathoverflow stackexchange. Should be e and n coprime ($gcd(e,n)$) to hold that identity?

Comment: @Cryptomathician: well, if $e$ and $n$ are not relatively prime, then $e^{-1} \bmod (n \cdot \phi(n))$ wouldn't exist.

Comment: ok, got it. Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: is it a different question when I want to know when $y = x^{-1} ~(\text{mod}~ k \cdot \phi(n))$ holds, so that also $xy \equiv 1 ~(\text{mod}~ \phi(n))$ holds for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ ? I was trying to figuring out when this holds, too. @poncho

Comment: @Cryptomathician: actually, it holds for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$; same sort of logic: $y = x^{-1} \pmod{k \phi(n)}$ means there is a $k' \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $yx = 1 + k'( k \phi(n))$; this implies that there is a $k''$ with $yx = 1 + k'' \phi(n)$, that is, $yz \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(n)}$

Comment: Ok, thank you. I did the same calculation as you did and wanted to be sure that I don't made a mistake. Thank you! Probably the last equation should be $yx \equiv 1 ~(\text{mod}~ \phi(n))$ instead of $yz \equiv 1 ~(\text{mod}~ \phi(n))$ right?

Comment: @Cryptomathician: correct, $yz$ was a typo...